firefox: "edit bookmark" window is comically small
it is impossible to browse through the bookmark hierarchy
the window is miniature under normal circumstances, but especially on large monitor:

can the size be changed with css customizations?
I am using Firefox 115 on linux
EDIT
I found I can change the width using:
#editBookmarkPanel {
  width: 1000px !important;
}

but setting height: 1400px !important; has no effect. So how can I change the height ?

Wouldn't it be better to set a higher DPI in windows, so everything is larger for all applications?

@LPChip - what windows? I am using linux

@LPChip - it literally says:  "I am using Firefox 115 on linux"

My apologies. I somehow missed that.

Update to a newer version of Firefox to see if the issue has been fixed. If you use Snap, which is not frequently updated, use Mozilla as PPA to get the latest version.

Did you also try changing max-height to none?
